# How to reduce for loops in a moving window based operation?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to reduce for loops in a moving window based operation? I'm using a 15x15 window across two images and performing multiplication to get average value per pixel.

[image]

```
    [ma,na]=size(g);
z= (win1 -1)/2;%centre of window
ini=z+1;
 for i= ini :(ma-z)
     for j= ini:(na-z)
          for a= (i-z):(i+z)    
              for b=(j-z):(j+z)
                  W(pp,qq)= g(a, b);%window on image
                  Es(pp,qq)=edg(a,b);%window on edge
                  qq=qq+1;
              end
              qq=1;
              pp=pp+1;
          end 
          pp=1;
   E(i,j)=sum(sum(W.*Es))/sum(sum(Es));
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

I might have gotten lost in your loops and i can't exactly read the formula (it's a bit fuzzy) but i think this is what you want:

```
g = rand(5); %sample img1
edg = rand(5); %sample img2
windowsize = 3; %set this to 15 for real images

A = g.*edg; % multiply each element beforehand, corresponds to mu*sigma in formula
B = movsum(movsum(A,windowsize,2),windowsize,1); % get moving window sum of A, corresponds to numerator in formula
C = movsum(movsum(edg,windowsize,2),windowsize,1); % get moving window sum of edg, corresponds to denominator in formula
E = B./C; %hopefully what you wanted
```

Ps: You need 2016a or newer to run this